Room booking app available on MS Teams
Good day!
Can you please recommend a room booking app available on MS Teams?
Here's the requirement:

system/app admin can customize the open time for bookings. For example, booking of room(s) is only open 12 o'clock midnight 1 day before.

ideally it has a feature to handle "no show". For example, if a room is booked and utilized, the person who used it can log the use. (in case rooms are booked but never used)


Thank you!
